# how to pass the already running db connection into the mongo store for storing sessions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, express-session

I am new to backend development so I am facing some problems.
I have used `mongoose.connection()` to connect my db into the server.
Now I want to store the user sessions into the database and for that I have used `express-session` and`mongo-store` for that. To create `mongo-store` instance, I have to again pass the database string and its other options to run a new db connection. Can I overcome this somehow ?

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');
require('dotenv').config();
const app = express();

//Passport config
require('./config/passport');

// //Connect To DB
const dbOptions = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
}
//--------------Here I have created a connection with the database----------------------//
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_String, dbOptions)
  .then(() => { console.log("Connected to the databse....") })
  .catch(error => console.log('Error While Connecting to db', error));

//Middleware to read the body of requests
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

//Express session middleware
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.Session_Secret,
  resave: true,
//---------Here I am creating a new connection with the database for storing sessions--------//
  store: MongoStore.create({
    mongoUrl: process.env.DB_String,
    mongoOptions: dbOptions,
    collection: 'sessions'
  }),
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
  }
}));


//Passport middlewares
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//Endpoints
app.use('/api/', require('./api/index'));

app.use('*', (req, res) => {
  res.status(404).json({message: 'Route not found'});
})
//Listen to the port
app.listen(process.env.port, () => {
  console.log(`app is listening on port ${process.env.port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```js
store: Mongostore.create({  
mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection
})
```

And if this doesnt work declare your mongostore like this:

```js
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
```

Comment: It is throwing an error 
**Assertion failed: You must provide either mongoUrl|clientPromise|client in options**
C:\Users\91836\Documents\vishal\clean\clean-backend\node_modules\connect-mongo\build\main\lib\MongoStore.js:119
            throw new Error('Cannot init client. Please provide correct options');

Comment: I have edited my answer, it should work now, if not i don't reallly know what else to do, sorry if it doesn't fix your problem